# Django template variable lookup of encoded object

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-templates

When I query my encoded object with

```
{{ map_settings }}
```

I get the encoded object like this:

```
{  &quot;geometry&quot;: {   &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Point&quot;,   &quot;coordinates&quot;: [    50,    4   ]  },  &quot;type&quot;: &quot;Feature&quot;,  &quot;properties&quot;: {  ...
```

However, I need to access only the element "geometry" (printing the whole object inside the client code would be too big).

Neither {{ map_settings.geometry }} nor {{ map_settings|safe.geometry }} does work.

Anyone has an idea how to only print the geometry element of this encoded object?

***EDIT

snippet from views.py:

```
map_settings['properties'].update(properties)
context['map_settings'] = simplejson.dumps(map_settings, indent=settings.DEBUG)
```

[Link to full views.py (Github)](https://github.com/umap-project/django-leaflet-storage/blob/master/leaflet_storage/views.py#L127)

Comment: Show us your view code. It looks like you are passing the `map_settings` as string and not dict.

Comment: @beezz does that help? Unfortunately I do not have access to the views.py part. If it is a string, this would mean the lookup is not working right?

Comment: exactly that's the problem. Dictionary lookup won't work for string. You can create templatetag which will turn your json string back to object or process that json with javascript.

Comment: @beezz could you explain how to use templatetag to turn string to object as an answer, so I can mark it as answered?

Comment: Why are you dumping it as JSON in the first place? Why not send `map_settings` directly to the template as a dict, then you won't have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit hacky solution but if (for some reason) you can't change the view to return object instead of json formatted string. You can use templatetag to turn it from json string back to object.

[How to create your custom templatetag.](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#custom-template-tags-and-filters)

For this task we'll use [assignment tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#assignment-tags)

Also [simple tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags) can do the trick.

So, in your app create `templatetags` directory which must have `__init__.py`.

Create e.g. `json_to_obj.py` in that directory. Now the content of `json_to_obj.py` may look something like this.

```
import json
from django import template

register = template.Library()


@register.assignment_tag
def json_to_obj(json_str):
    return json.loads(json_str)
```

To use the `json_to_obj` templatetag in your template:

```
{% load json_to_obj %}
{# on the top of your template load the templatetag library #}
...
{% json_to_obj map_settings as map_settings_obj %}
<p>{{ map_settings_obj.geometry }}</p>
```